# Should I reference an object variable's name from within the object's implementation?

Tags: javascript, this, object-literal

Is there any difference between (setting a property value) with :

```
var obj = {
    getData: function ()
    {
        this.age = 34      //notice this
    }
}
obj.getData();
alert(obj.age) //34
```

vs

```
var obj = {
    getData: function ()
    {
        obj.age = 34     //notice obj
    }
}
obj.getData();
alert(obj.age) //34
```

when should I use each ?

Comment: Did one of them give the wrong result ? How are we supposed to decide which is the correct one ?

Comment: Either works, either is correct.

Comment: Writing the object code so that it relies on a particular name seems undesirable to me.

Comment: What made you think there is a **wrong** way?

Comment: @dystroy did you read the question ?

Comment: Yes I did. And both ways are correct, or incorrect, depending on the context, as they have different consequences.

Comment: @dystroy ok I'll rephrase. ( editing)

Comment: Try this: `var foo = obj; obj = 5; foo.getData();` and tell me which of your approaches still works ;) OT: Naming functions which *set* something as *`getX`* is confusing.

Comment: @FelixKling yup, that's exactly the reassignment and re-use case I mentioned in my answer

Comment: @FelixKling so there **IS** a correct way and a less correct way. :-)

Comment: @FelixKling can you please answer my comment to Alnitak  ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The former is (IMHO) strongly preferred, although both "work" in these limited circumstances.

Wherever possible, an object should never refer to itself by the name it's given in its declaration.

Using `this` ensures that if the object is assigned another alias, and `obj` re-used, that the object still correctly refers to itself.  Likewise if you decide to rename `obj` - you only have to change it once.

Comment: +1, but I wouldn't call it _correct_ but better or something like it.

Comment: `var foo = obj; obj = 5;foo.getData();` foo is referencing to obj. obj is set to 5. so foo.getData() should fail. why it doesnt fail ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir in Chrome at least, it seems you can't add properties to a primitive variable.

Comment: @gdoron I tend to disagree. Felix sample shows clearly that if you..[...] it can crash. so we can avoid it. meaning it is the **correct** way of doing it.

Comment: @RoyiNamir I don't know what you're doing, but for me if I assign `var foo = 5` and then `foo.age = 35` then `foo.age` does _not_ get created.  Same in Chrome _and_ Firefox

Comment: @RoyiNamir no, I was talking about primitive variables, as per Felix's example as to why your second code sample isn't suitable for use.

Comment: @Alnitak let's take one step back. I dont understand why this code is working http://jsbin.com/ibinom/2/edit after we set 5

Comment: @RoyiNamir: Because you are using `this`! It would not work as expected if you where using `obj`.

Answer (score 1):

Doing this:

```
getData: function ()
{
    this.age = 34      //notice this
}
```

Has the following advantages:

1. If you ever need to rename `obj` to something else, your functions don't have to change because they refer to the object as `this`.
2. It's more portable; if you ever need the same functionality elsewhere, in another object, it's easier to copy / paste.

**About click handlers**

Having said that, care must be taken when your code is ever used in click handlers. For instance:

```
var obj = {
    value: 'hello world',
    doSomething: function ()
    {
        alert(this.value);
    }
}

// find first <div> on the page and attach click handler
var firstDiv = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
firstDiv.addEventListener('click', obj.doSomething, false);
```

When the `<div>` is clicked, it will call `obj.doSomething`, but `this` now references the `window` object, which is unexpected and your code will alert "undefined".

To fix it, you need to write a helper function:

```
firstDiv.addEventListener('click', function() {
    obj.doSomething();
}, false);
```

Comment: -1 for your second example.  IMHO it's a bad idea to fudge a function reference so that it works that way when you've aliased away its context.  I can't remember the number of times I've answered questions when people _incorrectly_ expect such a function to work.

Comment: @Alnitak It's just an example really and its behaviour is explained. I don't see how that warrants a downvote.

Comment: because IMHO it's a bad example and poor practice and will confuse readers.

Comment: @Alnitak Well, fwiw, I've added the necessary warning in the code.

Comment: and I've removed my downvote.  I still think your answer would be stronger without the example, though.  Noob readers need to understand that a bare function reference loses its context.

Comment: @Alnitak Fair enough, updated the second part with a somewhat more practical scenario.